# Call a Dart const from a String version of its name

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `Flutter` and the `FontAwesome` library and I need to create icons based on their name. So, I need to get the following:

```
FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.lightWalking);
```

...but from its name as a `String`.
Something like this:

```
FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons["lightWalking"]); // <== this doesn't work in Dart
```

I can then build a function to return icons based on the name that I get out of a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a dart related question on first sight but rather a FontAwesomeIcons question unless you want to use reflection in dart. You need to access the Icons here which are simply not accessible the way you tried it.

See the following issue:

https://github.com/fluttercommunity/font_awesome_flutter/issues/102

Quote:

> Hi, we don't support icon maps officially, but you can use this
> generator by calling it in the updater tool. You will need a local
> installation of font awesome for this, please follow the instructions
> for pro icons and ignore steps that mention icons.json or .ttf files.
> If you need further assistance feel free to ask.

That means the way you are trying to access your icons is not supported directly.
However you could use the generator tools to create such a map, iterate it and find a suitable icon. See the FontAwesome example for that (they generated a map and iterated it).

https://github.com/fluttercommunity/font_awesome_flutter/tree/master/example/lib

What might be a little more convenient might be a third party tool which already has such a map and allows you to search it.

https://pub.dev/packages/icons_helper/example

You can then do the following:

`getIconUsingPrefix(name: "PREFIX.ICON_NAME")`

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I was able to build a map of the icons although it doesn't give me the Pro styles so I may build my own class to get the details from the icons.json file and then I just need to convert from a unicode string to the right font. thanks.

Comment: btw, icons_helper was incomplete so not usable

Comment: Here's the map: https://gist.github.com/leeprobert/b98c5e1bb41408b0c4a229cc467182d9

Comment: Glad I could help! I'm not sure about pro icons and the generator :(

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this only using reflection. There is a library called [reflectable](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable) for Flutter. It will generate some code for you and then you will be able to access the class members of FontAwesomeIcons by their name as String.